# Destiny Audio Drops / problems

Tags: destiny

I've been playing destiny on PS4 for over two months now.  Love the game, but have one big problem that is making me crazy...While playing, usually during a firefight (lot of action going on) my audio will randomly drop out, completely no music no gun sounds nothing, kinda like I turned the sound off.  It will stay off for a second then come back on.  I have contacted Sony numerous times about the problem, with no straight answer (just reformat your system etc) I have posted in bungie's forums with no reply from them.  I don't know where else to turn.  I just want a straight forward answer to what is causing this.  Is it my system?  Is it the game? Is it my internet connection (I have charter 60 mbs hardlined in,  but an older wireless rounter)  I have tried to switch hdmi cords (using my x box 360 one now with same audio drops.  I just need an answer, it's driving me crazy, please someone help.

Comment: This happens infrequently to me as well.  I think it's just a bug in the game.  I've never looked for a solution though, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: I find it happens on pregen consoles more, when internet has been slowed or someone else has the ports in use. My theory is that it is generally when used on external storage. Is this the case?

Comment: Not sure if the edit posted but I think it is to do with external storage being used for Destiny.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your talking about pregen?  I bought my console in August, batman bundle.  And not sure about ports? Any way I can change it?  I bought fall out 4 yesterday, have about 8 hours play time in, no audio drops.  I just want to be able to play destiny and not worry about looking for audio cutouts.  I played a little tonight, destiny that is, and had 3 cutouts.  Any ideas how to fix it? , thanks for your help

Comment: All parts of the game?  It's a known bug in Prison of Elders, happens nearly every time.  It also happens in another older strike or raid, I can't remember which.

Comment: Happens during strikes and kings fall raid.  Random stikes, usually when a lot of action is going on.  I just want an answer, is it my tv? Ps4? Game?